# Finding all the perfect cubes made from the sum of 3 other perfect cubes within a given parameter

Tags: python

Me and a friend of mine were attempting to do this but had no luck and ended up with this. (We still have a fairly basic knowledge regarding python, and this is my first time using stack overflow.)

```
cubelist = []

while True: 
  maxcube = int(input("What is the maximum parameter: "))

  for i in range(1, maxcube):
    nums = i 
    nums = abs(nums)
    if round(nums ** (1 / 3)) ** 3 == nums:
      
      cubelist.append(i)
    
  break

print(cubelist)  


pos = 0
while True :
  CubeSum = cubelist[pos] + cubelist[pos+1] + cubelist[pos+2]
  pos += 1
  for i in cubelist:
    if CubeSum > i:
      cubelist.remove(cubelist[len(cubelist)-1])

    if CubeSum == i:
      print(CubeSum)
      print("Valid")
      
    if CubeSum < i:
      print(CubeSum)
      print("Invalid")
      
  break
```

Comment: So what is your question for us? Just saying that you had "no luck" isn't descriptive enough. Does your code give an error? The wrong answer? No answer at all? What have you attempted to do to diagnose the issue? This site doesn't really do general discussion about code, we try to stick quite strictly to our Q&A format. For some guidance on how to write questions that work well here, check out [Ask]. And take the [tour] to learn more about the site and how it works.

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to achieve through your code, expected outcome and current outcome

Answer (score 0):

you are making the sum in the wrong way, only taking three consecutive elements. you should iterate over the `cubelist` list with three different indexes if you want to find all possible combinations. Also, you are performing too much calculations when finding `cubelist` too. check this solution:

```
cubelist = []

maxcube = int(input("What is the maximum parameter: "))
counter = 1
while True:
    cube = counter ** 3
    if cube <= maxcube:
        cubelist.append(cube)
        counter += 1
    else: break
print(cubelist)  


pos = 0
ln = len(cubelist)
for i in range(ln-2):
    for j in range(i+1, ln-1):
        for k in range(j+1, ln):
            _sum = cubelist[i] + cubelist[j] + cubelist[k]
            if _sum in cubelist:
                print('{0}={1}+{2}+{3} => valid'.format(_sum, cubelist[i], cubelist[j], cubelist[k]))
            #else:
            #    print('{0} => invalid'.format(_sum))
```

my output:

```
What is the maximum parameter: 10000
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729, 1000, 1331, 1728, 2197, 2744, 3375, 4096, 4913, 5832, 6859, 8000, 9261]
729=1+216+512 => valid
5832=8+1728+4096 => valid
216=27+64+125 => valid
6859=27+1000+5832 => valid
1728=216+512+1000 => valid
8000=343+2744+4913 => valid
5832=729+1728+3375 => valid
```